# eclipse very slow to start a plugin install

Tags: eclipse

I use eclipse for my projects.

When I want to install or update a plugin, it is very very slow to calculate dependencies ( about 5 to 10 minutes) and then it is fast to download files and install them.

Do you know how to solve that ?

It is on Ubuntu 10.04 with latest patches + eclipse 3.6.1

No proxy is used. I noticed the problem with several computer at home, but I do not have this problem at work (I use a proxy at work)

Comment: Try to uncheck the option "Contract all update sites" before installing your selection.

Comment: @Kane, but why as comment. This is probably the answer...

Comment: @zvikico, I just realized that I should answer it after commenting it.

Comment: It took me about 25 minutes to install maven while I was conducting a class where most of them are from .NET camp, which give them bad impression of Java tool's quality...

Comment: @Eric - Care to accept an answer?

Answer (score 68):

Try to uncheck the option "Contract all update sites" before installing your selection. Because p2 would try to check the dependency from all the available update sites(download the metadata repository firstly) when checking that option.

[image]

Comment: It was taking much longer for me and then I realized I'm behind a proxy and it was contacting each update site and timing out. Thanks!

Comment: Huge time saver for those plugins that don't have any dependencies.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for Marketplace installs as well?

Comment: @haggai_e, No such option for Marketplace. If you are sure Eclipse always searches all repositories when installing something from Marketplace, pls open bug against 'RT - Equinox - P2'.

Comment: I wonder why I never saw this checkbox, probably was not looking for one :)

Answer (score 2):

I had very similar issue in Windows recently, but finally I managed to figure out what is causing the extremely slow network connections in Eclipse.
Actually the issue isn't the low bandwidth, but connection **timeouts**.
The solution in my case was to **disable all unnecessary network adapters** in Windows like Hamachi's and TeamViewer's adapter. I know you are on Ubuntu, but I'm sure the root of the issue in your case is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Windows Defender and other Antivirus/spyware can help. Maybe the speed up is not so high, but at least it will run faster.