# Eclipse update and plugin installation is extremely slow

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eclipse very slow to start a plugin install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179612/eclipse-very-slow-to-start-a-plugin-install)

I installed Eclipse for JavaEE (Helios) and the update process seems to take forever (it's contacting software sites for an hour already). Same thing with plugin installation (it is calculating dependencies for half an hour). I run Eclipse on Ubuntu 11.04. Is there any way to speed up things?

Comment: The very first update/install process you launch in a given Eclipse is always really slow (unfortunately...). However, more than one hour is too long. Are you sure your Eclipse hasn't frozen and is not blocked by a firewall?

Comment: What do you try to update, a subset of the installed plug-ins or the whole Eclipse? If you are trying to update a subset, then @Kane is right in that this question is probably a duplicate.