# Installing ADT Plugin in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, eclipse-plugin

I am using windows 7 and trying to install ADT plugin in Eclipse.
I have tried with eclipse clasic 3.7, eclipse EE, Eclipse juno and with 4.2 also. In all cases eclipse couldn't install it. It halts at 35% to 50% . I have even put the system on for full night with 2 mbps dedicated internet(thought connection speed is problem) but in vain.

Comment: are you getting any error in eclipse console

Comment: am using eclipse 3.7.2 classic its installing without any problems

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions here http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html?

Comment: is there any solution or steps which you can tell me are essential and i might be mising...or any system requirement.

Comment: @babatenor yes i have followed that also

Comment: am using same eclipse version in windows 7 and it runs fine..

Comment: ADT requires Web development tools(WTP). Even if Eclipse will search it for you by default, you can try installing it firstly due to your slow Interenet connection. You can find it from default repository. After installing it, then install ADT from its repository. You'd better disable the option to 'contact to available software sites' to speed up the installation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179612/eclipse-very-slow-to-start-a-plugin-install/4182759#4182759

Comment: i more thing which i forgot to mention is that a lot of files(over 50-60) keeping on download when the installation percentage stops..

Comment: @kane i try that and will let you know if it works.

Comment: thanks babatenor & kane ........ its working now...

Comment: You can try to install it from "Eclipse Marketplace"

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using "Eclipse Marketplace". The following steps might help you to install ADT plugin for eclipse:

1. Open Eclipse
2. Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
3. Search as "ADT plugin"
4. Click Install of "Android Development Tools for Eclipse" section
5. Click Next button and follow the eclipse instruction